# Use same browser session while using selenium with phpUnit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I have an application made in php for which am using selenium for unit testing using phpUnit. The problem is that I have to set the environment before I can go for tests. For eg. I have to set session variables, login and fetch data from remote server. All this takes a lot of time and it is not feasible to re-set this in every test function. 

I am looking for a method so that I can use the same browser session for running all the tests in it. I tried looking for resources online, but couldn't find any good sources for this. The code I have written is

```
protected function setUp()
{
  parent::setUp();
  $this->setBrowserUrl("http://localhost/devel/");
}

public function start()
{
  parent::start();
  $this->open("");
  //Setting up the environment here
}

public function testFunction()
{
   //A test function
}

public function testFunction2()
{
   //Another test function
}
```

But this is opening browser instance for both the functions. Is there any work around for this? Or is there any command line parameter while launching selenium server for this?

Comment: Why do you need to run all your tests in the same window? The point of the tests is that you test a self-contained part of your webapplication, right?

Answer (score 0):

"[I am] using selenium for unit testing using phpUnit"

No, you're not. You're using PHPUnit with selenium for functional testing. :-)

But since it's probably not in your best interest to re-invent that wheel, you want Mink: http://mink.behat.org/

It wraps around Guzzle and lets you do session-based acceptance testing using a bunch of different drivers. It has Goutte for a headless browser, and can work with Selenium and Sahi and a bunch of others.

Also of note, depending on your needs, is Behat: http://behat.org/

It lets you write client-readable test documents that can be turned into Mink-based acceptance tests.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Question already answered.
The unaccepted answer did the job for me.

@see [How do I run a PHPUnit Selenium test without having a new browser window run for each function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734237/how-do-i-run-a-phpunit-selenium-test-without-having-a-new-browser-window-run-for)